# Can't create a local repository.

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I just installed Source tree on my windows. I set the name, email fields and chose the default directory for repositories as C:\Users\repos [image]

And then in the new tab, I selected '+ Create'. But upon filling the

[image]

When I click Create, nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why but, after changing the path C:\repos\reposA. It started working!! (I previously specified this path C:Users\repos\reposA)